# How to write the results from output in robotframework to csv in dict format using python?

Tags: python, json, robotframework, key-value

I have a robot framework code that has multiple test cases with results. Now I need to store these results in JSON file in key-value pairs using python code. How can I do it?

Pythoncode.py

```
def writeJson(data):
    with open("data_file.json", "w") as write_file:
       json.dump(data, write_file)


Robot Code.robot


  TC1
   ${output}=    TC1test
   ${dict1}=    Set Variable     ${output}
   ${value_cnt}=    Get Length    ${dict1}
   ${var}=    set variable    ${dict1}

   TC2
   ${output}=   TC2test
    ${dict3}=    set variable    ${output}
   ${cnt}=    Get Length    ${dict3}
   ${var}=    set variable    ${dict3}
         : FOR    ${item}    IN RANGE   0    ${cnt}
         \    ${var2}=    Set Variable     ${var['value']} 

   write data
   ${json} =      writeJson         ${var1}   \n  ${var2}
```

Output:
datafile.json
only one value prints

I need help in coding part how to do this using python or robot framework code.

I need some example code

Comment: can anyone suggest python code for this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't even need to use a python library to achieve this. You could run something like:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections
Library  json
Library  OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Write data
   &{TESTS_DICT}=  Create Dictionary  FirstTestResults=PASS  SecondTestResult=FAIL
   ${JSON_CONTENT}=  json.dumps  ${TESTS_DICT}
   Create File  ${CURDIR}/data_file.json  content=${JSON_CONTENT}
```

If you want to use your own Python source file for writing to the file, you can do the following:

Pythoncode.py:

```
import json

def writeJson(data):
    with open("data_file.json", "w") as write_file:
       json.dump(data, write_file)
```

main.robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Pythoncode.py
Library  Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Write data
   &{TESTS_DICT}=  Create Dictionary  FirstTestResults=PASS  SecondTestResult=FAIL
   WriteJson         ${TESTS_DICT}
```

Running `main.robot` in either of the examples will create a json file `data_file.json` containing two key-value pairs. Output:

```
{"FirstTestResults": "PASS", "SecondTestResult": "FAIL"}
```